# How to publish a message to Kafka topic using spring cloud stream in reactive way [using webflux]?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

- Publish a message to kafka topic **without using StreamBridge** as it uses deprecated components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reactor API:

> All you need to do is declare a `Supplier<Flux<whatever>>` which returns
> `EmitterProcessor` from the reactor API (see Reactive Functions support
> for more details) to effectively provide a bridge between the actual
> event source (foreign source) and spring-cloud-stream. All you need to
> do now is feed the `EmitterProcessor` with data via
> `EmitterProcessor#onNext(data)` operation.
> Quoted from [spring cloud stream docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_reactor_api)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class WebSourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSourceApplication.class);
    }

    EmitterProcessor<String> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void delegateToSupplier(@RequestBody String body) {
        processor.onNext(body);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<String>> supplier() {
        return () -> this.processor;
    }
}
```

To send a message use curl `curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST -d "hello from the other side" http://localhost:8080/`